# update query execution in python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am executing this query on sql developer and it is working fine

```
update TABLE_X set COL_SID='19' where ID='1';
```

But when I am doing this via python code

```
cur=conn.cursor()
updt_query='update TABLE_X set COL_SID=? where ID=?'
cur.execute(updt_query,('19','1'))
cur.close()
```

I am getting error

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Please let me know where I am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the ID are number and not string so  you should use

```
 cur.execute(updt_query,(19,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a better way

```
cur=conn.cursor()
updt_query='update TABLE_X set COL_SID=:cs where ID=:id'
cur.execute(updt_query,{cs:'19',id:'1'})
cur.close()
```

Its done ! Thanks!